# Access is denied error whenever accessing Roaming folder, with any application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cmd, permissions, codeblocks

It seems that whenever I want to access the following pathways of C:\Users\ABC\AppData, any program or application gives me an "Access is denied error":

[image]

In another application called CodeBlocks, I get the same error:

Error: can't open C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4x6bY8.s for reading: Permission denied

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged as JavaScript. What happens when you try an open that file manually - do you actually have 'the appropriate permissions to access the item'?? (Is the path correct?)

Comment: @MikeBrockington yes. I am an administrator and i'm also running the cmd.exe in administrator. Further, I have edited each folder's security to have full control for all users.

Comment: Does that actually mean that Node runs as administrator though? (I would hope not.) Do the actual files have full access, or just the containing folder. Since it is a temp file, does it exist, does some other process have it open for writing?

Comment: @MikeBrockington, the file in question here, live-server.js is not a temporary file and no other processes have it open for writing. With that said, How would I go about running node as administrator? Since i'm running node through cmd?

Comment: The last part of your question states: "Error: can't open C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4x6bY8.s for reading"    Is that related or not?

Comment: @MikeBrockington, yes that is related, in the sense that I find these "permission is denied" errors to be related to the AppData folder pathway. CodeBlocks is an entirely different application, yet it gives me the same permission errors when it is handling the AppData folders.

Comment: AppData is a little bit 'special' so this question might get more interest on a Windows forum?